# JSON String is incorrectly mapped to textviews

Tags: java, android, json, youtube, textview

I have 3 textviews which I'm attempting to populate with data from a JSON Http response however they are currently being populated with the incorrect data from the response.

For some reason it isn't parsing the fields and assigning them correctly - it appears it simply fills each textview with the beginning of the data from the JSON response.

### SCREENSHOT:

[image]

### JSON HTTP RESPONSE:

```
{
 "version": "1.0",
 "encoding": "UTF-8",
 "feed": {
  "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
  "xmlns$openSearch": "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/",
  "xmlns$gd": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005",
  "xmlns$yt": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007",
  "gd$etag": "W/\"Ak8ASXk-fCp7I2A9Wh5VGEg.\"",
  "id": {
   "$t": "tag:youtube.com,2008:video:PYvyGZwHlKg:comments"
  },
  "updated": {
   "$t": "2013-12-12T14:34:08.754Z"
  },
  "category": [
   {
    "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
    "term": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comment"
   }
  ],
  "logo": {
   "$t": "http://www.gstatic.com/youtube/img/logo.png"
  },
  "link": [
   {
    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed",
    "type": "application/atom+xml",
    "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/PYvyGZwHlKg/comments?v=2"
   },
   {
    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch",
    "type": "application/atom+xml",
    "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/PYvyGZwHlKg/comments/batch?v=2"
   },
   {
    "rel": "self",
    "type": "application/atom+xml",
    "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/PYvyGZwHlKg/comments?alt=json&max-results=50&v=2"
   },
   {
    "rel": "service",
    "type": "application/atomsvc+xml",
    "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/PYvyGZwHlKg/comments?alt=atom-service&v=2"
   },
   {
    "rel": "next",
    "type": "application/atom+xml",
    "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/PYvyGZwHlKg/comments?alt=json&alt=json&start-token=Gq4ECqsECDISpgQACgAAAEQAJYAEABUBAAACAJUIACgAIAABABAAABAgAAAQABAALSAAAgQQBQBAAQAgRgAQAAABAAAJBAAAAkACBAAIAACYCgAIABBAIAAACAAAQAABAEAAAAAAEAADACCAABgAggAACgIQgAAAAAEICAlRk0YAgAAAAgAASAAIEgUQAAhAgACAAIgABAIgAAAAAAAiAAAAABSMQCAgAAAAAAIAASAAgAhQggABASAAAAAiADQQiAAgSAKQGIAABAAANAAAgAGSAAgEEAhABkAAAAEhCBAAgEAoAIAIAggCgAQACCICgQAgAAAoAAAgoCQAAAAEgEEAAAgAAkEEGAECACASAAiQADAAAIKAGKAABAEAKAAAQCEBCAIAABAAAAAACGAACAIIHABACAABRAEAAQAAQgAAAwGKoABIAAAkABAEAaAJAAgIKAAACgARAARAgoJEQCBIEAABBAEAAAFEAAAyQAAAACCBgAUCAghACBIFAIAwBAAgACBFACBAgAQAFQACAEAgACBEAgBAIFgJAwBIAADECCgAQAAAUIAAgAAQAAoAIDUAgIAAABAAAAmAAgAACiACAgiBEAAAABCBAwBACQggAB4CAoAABIBAKBAACBAISBgAqAEQEIUQRAIAAADCBCAAEQCAACBAAiAAAABDCIAAAAAAQAAAAEQCBwABAAIIAAAIAgECAAAkAgQABAAQAAAAgEERCAAIAQAgAAABAAAAKOiX8qy6oLsCMLmMmejzqrsCOAFAAQ%3D%3D&max-results=50&v=2"
   }
  ],
  "author": [
   {
    "name": {
     "$t": "YouTube"
    },
    "uri": {
     "$t": "http://www.youtube.com/"
    }
   }
  ],
  "generator": {
   "$t": "YouTube data API",
   "version": "2.1",
   "uri": "http://gdata.youtube.com"
  },
  "openSearch$totalResults": {
   "$t": 75
  },
  "openSearch$itemsPerPage": {
   "$t": 50
  },
  "entry": [
   {
    "gd$etag": "W/\"A08GR347eCp7I2A9Wh5VFEQ.\"",
    "id": {
     "$t": "tag:youtube.com,2008:video:PYvyGZwHlKg:comment:z133w5xy2kzrv1xjk04cfvpimyzczvw4hjs"
    },
    "published": {
     "$t": "2013-12-08T10:50:26.000Z"
    },
    "updated": {
     "$t": "2013-12-08T10:50:26.000Z"
    },
    "category": [
     {
      "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
      "term": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comment"
     }
    ],
    "title": {
     "$t": "SUPER [MARIO] CHAO ..."
    },
    "content": {
     "$t": "SUPER [MARIO] CHAO !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\ufeff"
    },
    "link": [
     {
      "rel": "related",
      "type": "application/atom+xml",
      "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/PYvyGZwHlKg?v=2"
     },
     {
      "rel": "alternate",
      "type": "text/html",
      "href": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYvyGZwHlKg"
     },
     {
      "rel": "self",
      "type": "application/atom+xml",
      "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/PYvyGZwHlKg/comments/z133w5xy2kzrv1xjk04cfvpimyzczvw4hjs?v=2"
     }
    ],
    "author": [
     {
      "name": {
       "$t": "Max Elymanov"
      },
      "uri": {
       "$t": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/answer37"
      },
      "yt$userId": {
       "$t": "J4HQsbLcybybImJBXr4hmA"
      }
     }
    ],
    "yt$channelId": {
     "$t": "UCJ4HQsbLcybybImJBXr4hmA"
    },
    "yt$googlePlusUserId": {
     "$t": "104133629856589391856"
    },
    "yt$replyCount": {
     "$t": 0
    },
    "yt$videoid": {
     "$t": "PYvyGZwHlKg"
    }
   },
   {
    "gd$etag": "W/\"C04MRH47eCp7I2A9Wh5SFEk.\"",
    "id": {
     "$t": "tag:youtube.com,2008:video:PYvyGZwHlKg:comment:U5wNTjpckuNXWhtdUX34uhfdzQqy534u2-Tb-aMCsRM"
    },
    "published": {
     "$t": "2013-10-10T21:53:05.000Z"
    },
    "updated": {
     "$t": "2013-10-10T21:53:05.000Z"
    },
    "category": [
     {
      "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
      "term": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comment"
     }
    ],
    "title": {
     "$t": "oooooo the best ..."
    },
    "content": {
     "$t": "oooooo the best saludoss manu chaoo desde ubrique ( cadiz )"
    },
    "link": [
     {
      "rel": "related",
      "type": "application/atom+xml",
      "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/PYvyGZwHlKg?v=2"
     },
     {
      "rel": "alternate",
      "type": "text/html",
      "href": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYvyGZwHlKg"
     },
     {
      "rel": "self",
      "type": "application/atom+xml",
      "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/PYvyGZwHlKg/comments/U5wNTjpckuNXWhtdUX34uhfdzQqy534u2-Tb-aMCsRM?v=2"
     }
    ],
    "author": [
     {
      "name": {
       "$t": "Juan Antonio Gago"
      },
      "uri": {
       "$t": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/u22Kbw-Z9GDEYLcuHBMX_w"
      },
      "yt$userId": {
       "$t": "u22Kbw-Z9GDEYLcuHBMX_w"
      }
     }
    ],
    "yt$channelId": {
     "$t": "UCu22Kbw-Z9GDEYLcuHBMX_w"
    },
    "yt$replyCount": {
     "$t": 0
    },
    "yt$videoid": {
     "$t": "PYvyGZwHlKg"
    }
   },
   {
    "gd$etag": "W/\"CUEMRX47eCp7I2A9WhFaEEQ.\"",
    "id": {
     "$t": "tag:youtube.com,2008:video:PYvyGZwHlKg:comment:U5wNTjpckuNls5OqMHC6zITllTb7jijbNb2XxEyaum8"
    },
    "published": {
     "$t": "2013-09-13T17:34:44.000Z"
    },
    "updated": {
     "$t": "2013-09-13T17:34:44.000Z"
    },
    "category": [
     {
      "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
      "term": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comment"
     }
    ],
    "title": {
     "$t": "peligrosamente ..."
    },
    "content": {
     "$t": "peligrosamente excelente!!! no tengo palabras para definir lo bueno q \nsiento q este concierto es... genial!"
    },
    "link": [
     {
      "rel": "related",
      "type": "application/atom+xml",
      "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/PYvyGZwHlKg?v=2"
     },
     {
      "rel": "alternate",
      "type": "text/html",
      "href": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYvyGZwHlKg"
     },
     {
      "rel": "self",
      "type": "application/atom+xml",
      "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/PYvyGZwHlKg/comments/U5wNTjpckuNls5OqMHC6zITllTb7jijbNb2XxEyaum8?v=2"
     }
    ],
    "author": [
     {
      "name": {
       "$t": "PALOMA ROSAS"
      },
      "uri": {
       "$t": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/3myOrO39fEOgdJt9UAoP3g"
      },
      "yt$userId": {
       "$t": "3myOrO39fEOgdJt9UAoP3g"
      }
     }
    ],
    "yt$channelId": {
     "$t": "UC3myOrO39fEOgdJt9UAoP3g"
    },
    "yt$replyCount": {
     "$t": 0
    },
    "yt$videoid": {
     "$t": "PYvyGZwHlKg"
    }
   },
   {
    "gd$etag": "W/\"CE8EQX47eCp7I2A9WhFbEEo.\"",
    "id": {
     "$t": "tag:youtube.com,2008:video:PYvyGZwHlKg:comment:U5wNTjpckuMLAEj5sQvw2XuQ9mtVRvhpvmq5LsUXGJw"
    },
    "published": {
     "$t": "2013-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "updated": {
     "$t": "2013-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "category": [
     {
      "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
      "term": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comment"
     }
    ],
    "title": {
     "$t": "coincido 2000%"
    },
    "content": {
     "$t": "coincido 2000%"
    },
    "link": [
     {
      "rel": "related",
      "type": "application/atom+xml",
      "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/PYvyGZwHlKg?v=2"
     },
     {
      "rel": "alternate",
      "type": "text/html",
      "href": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYvyGZwHlKg"
     },
     {
      "rel": "self",
      "type": "application/atom+xml",
      "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/PYvyGZwHlKg/comments/U5wNTjpckuMLAEj5sQvw2XuQ9mtVRvhpvmq5LsUXGJw?v=2"
     }
    ],
    "author": [
     {
      "name": {
       "$t": "juan agus"
      },
      "uri": {
       "$t": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/0Fm76n0qFloO9YGwf9sYTg"
      },
      "yt$userId": {
       "$t": "0Fm76n0qFloO9YGwf9sYTg"
      }
     }
    ],
    "yt$channelId": {
     "$t": "UC0Fm76n0qFloO9YGwf9sYTg"
    },
    "yt$replyCount": {
     "$t": 0
    },
    "yt$videoid": {
     "$t": "PYvyGZwHlKg"
    }
   },
   {
    "gd$etag": "W/\"CkcHSH47eCp7I2A9WhVXFEg.\"",
    "id": {
     "$t": "tag:youtube.com,2008:video:PYvyGZwHlKg:comment:U5wNTjpckuNbsu4nD4cjeCFQCCMd-lqal5eptQ-INlE"
    },
    "published": {
     "$t": "2012-04-15T00:33:59.000Z"
    },
    "updated": {
     "$t": "2012-04-15T00:33:59.000Z"
    },
    "category": [
     {
      "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
      "term": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comment"
     }
    ],
    "title": {
     "$t": "manu chao c'est ..."
    },
    "content": {
     "$t": "manu chao c'est trop bon c'est du bonheur en vidéo concert yeaaaahh !!!!"
    },
    "link": [
     {
      "rel": "related",
      "type": "application/atom+xml",
      "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/PYvyGZwHlKg?v=2"
     },
     {
      "rel": "alternate",
      "type": "text/html",
      "href": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYvyGZwHlKg"
     },
     {
      "rel": "self",
      "type": "application/atom+xml",
      "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/PYvyGZwHlKg/comments/U5wNTjpckuNbsu4nD4cjeCFQCCMd-lqal5eptQ-INlE?v=2"
...
79900
0
0
```

### JAVA:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);
        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        String uploader = getIntent().getStringExtra("uploader");
        String viewCount = getIntent().getStringExtra("viewCount");
        TextView titleTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
        TextView uploaderTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uploaderTv);
        TextView viewCountTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewCountTv);

        titleTv.setText(title);
        uploaderTv.setText("by" + uploader + " |");
        viewCountTv.setText(viewCount + " views");
        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);



        Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        GetYouTubeUserCommentsTask task = new GetYouTubeUserCommentsTask(handler , viewCount);




        task.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onInitializationFailure()",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            String video_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
            player.loadVideo(video_id);
        }
    }

    public final class GetYouTubeUserCommentsTask extends
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        public static final String LIBRARY = "CommentsLibrary";
        private final Handler replyTo;
        private final String username;
        String video_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");

        public GetYouTubeUserCommentsTask(Handler replyTo, String username) {
            this.replyTo = replyTo;
            this.username = username;
        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(
                        "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"
                                + video_id
                                + "/comments?v=2&alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=50&prettyprint=true");

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

                String jsonString = StreamUtils.convertToString(response
                        .getEntity().getContent());

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray(
                        "entry");

                List<Comments> comments = new ArrayList<Comments>();

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = jsonObject.optString("name","defaultValue");
                    String content = jsonObject.optString("content","defaultValue");
                    String published = jsonObject.optString("published","defaultValue");

                    comments.add(new Comments(name, content, published));
                }

                CommentsLibrary lib = new CommentsLibrary(jsonString, jsonString, jsonString);

                Bundle data = new Bundle();
                data.putSerializable(LIBRARY, lib);

                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.setData(data);
                replyTo.sendMessage(msg);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.e("Feck", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Feck", e);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Feck", e);
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            TextView nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);   
            nameTv.setText(com.idg.omv.domain.CommentsLibrary.getName());

            TextView contentTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content); 
            contentTv.setText(com.idg.omv.domain.CommentsLibrary.getContent());

            TextView publishedTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.published); 
            publishedTv.setText(com.idg.omv.domain.CommentsLibrary.getPublished());
        }
    }
}
```

### CommentsLibrary

```
public class CommentsLibrary implements Serializable{
    // The username of the owner of the comment
    private static String name;
    // The  comment
        private static String content;
    // The date the comment was published
    private static String published;

    public CommentsLibrary(String name, String content, String published) {
        this.name = name;
        this.content = content;
        this.published = published;
    }

    /**
     * @return the user name
     */
    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the videos
     */
    public static String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    /**
     * @return the videos
     */
    public static String getPublished() {
        return published;
    }
}
```

Comment: show CommentsLibrary class

Comment: your code is similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527966/textview-isnt-updated-with-json-response/20528402#20528402. r they related???.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
CommentsLibrary lib = new CommentsLibrary(jsonString, jsonString, jsonString);
```

All params passed to the constructor of CommentsLibrary is `jsonString`. All the three have the same jsonstring.

```
public CommentsLibrary(String name, String content, String published) {
        this.name = name;
        this.content = content;
        this.published = published;
    }
```

So its the same content that is displayed when you get method for the corresponding fields

Edit:

Declare list as a instance variable

```
 ArrayList<CommentsLibrary> list = new ArrayList<CommentsLibrary>();
```

Then

```
     for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     String name = jsonObject.optString("name","defaultValue");
     String content = jsonObject.optString("content","defaultValue");
     String published = jsonObject.optString("published","defaultValue");
     list.add(new CommentsLibrary(name, content, published));
     }
```

Then in `onPostExecute`

Use a ListView witha custom adapter and populate the listview with the `ArrayList list`.

With text view you only see 1 set of values.

Comment: I posted the contents of CommentsLibrary - should I use: CommentsLibrary lib = new CommentsLibrary(content, published, name); instead?

Comment: @user3009687 yes by the way is it related to the question in the comment i posted?

Comment: @user3009687 only 1 set of values will be displayed. you need a listview not textviews.

Comment: @user3009687 why do you need textviews you probably want a listview. A custom listview to display all the contents. Textview won't display all data.

Comment: Hmmm... would I use something such as:  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   ListView comments = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.comments); 
   comments.setText(com.idg.omv.domain.CommentsLibrary.getName());

Comment: listview does not have settext method. pls ask a new question with details. pls study the docs that is the first effort from your side

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549782/replacing-json-populated-textview-with-json-populated-listview